# What happens when you put a battery in saltwater?

Tags: electrochemistry, water

If somebody puts a battery in a salt solution, what path do the electrons take?

Comment: It depends on battery voltage.

Comment: If a question is asked on Chemistry SE site, then, in contrary to sites like Quora, it is expected the author elaborates the topic in the question by at least basic own topic review and writes what he/she understands and what is the eventual stumble stone. The "quick questions" without explicitly expressed particular effort are not very welcome, and may be closed.

Comment: Electrons do not take a path, it is the charged ions which act as messengers of current though an electrolyte as in an electrolytic cell.

Answer (score 2):

Salt dissolves in water to left behind positively charged sodium ion and negatively charged chloride ion. once you put battery in salt water, the sodium ion migrate towards the "negative tank" and chloride ion migrate towards the "positive tank". Salt water is much more conducive than regular water, so the battery would discharge more quickly and the current will break down the salt by electrolysis, producing hydrogen and chlorine gas.